# How to generate PostgreSQL COPY bin files?

Tags: postgresql, import

My Googlefu is failing me. Are there any code snippets, either in Python or FORTRAN, that shows how to create binary files to be used by the COPY command in PostgreSQL?

Comment: you mean how to create binary files which is used by copy commond? pg_restore with parameter -Fc can produce binary file.

Comment: Yes, but I want to generate the files from another application. I have a numerical model in Fortran that generate Gigabytes of data that I want to import to Postegresql as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet really is to create CSV files and then import them with COPY.  If you want to, you can then wrap them simply in a COPY ... WITH CSV FROM STDIN statement.

The existing docs on the COPY command should be sufficient.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html